# Change default data/dashboards in superset

Tags: apache-superset

I want to add default data to superset to deploy it on another machine with already created dashboards and data.
I added backup data from PostgreSQL inside postgres container

`docker cp /path/to/your/backup.sql postgres_container:/backup.sql`

Unpack DB

`docker exec -it d7e4c2803d5f psql -U superset -d finance -a -f /tmp/finance.sql`

I did not see new data in superset

Get my data, dashboards by default in superset

Comment: Okay, I solved problem with datasets. By default, metadata are stored in postgres container. If you connect another DB, it'll save metadata in postgres anyway.